# Is it possible to express lambda expressions/functions using Templates & Exception Handling?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Shall We can work the Lambda expressions with templates & Exception handling ?

Can any one able to show that in terms of an exapmle program please ?

Is it possible to express lambda expressions/functions using Templates & Exception Handling ?

EDIT: i need an example programs  .."Lambda Expression/Functyions using Templates & exception handling "

Comment: Lambdas work just like calling any other functor, so they do work as expected with exceptions.  You can't have a template lambda, though you can pass a lambda as a template argument.

Comment: @Cory : yeah in 23 point he gave an example with templates..but for me ..iam feeling ...that is not enough to understand .. can u please explain any simple examples ...

Comment: @user: To me, it is completely unclear what you are asking. Can you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user751747: Who is _he_ and what is _23 point_? I'll add a homework tag.

Comment: @ Phresnel,Cory : in n3290 Draft ,ISO C++ standard, Section :5.1.2  ,point 23 ,the example is template one

Comment: The example in section 5.1.2 is a lambda defined inside a function template. The lambda itself is not a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to a template. The simplest example is with `std::for_each`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
} 
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int& i){i*=2;}); // double each value
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int i){std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}); // print each value
```

This will thus print

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

You can also throw exceptions from a lambda, and catch them outside. e.g.

```
try
{
    unsigned count=0;

    std::for_each(
        v.begin(),v.end(),
        [&count](int i)
        {
            if(++count==5)
            {
                throw i;
            }
            std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        });
}
catch(int i)
{
    std::cout<<"Caught "<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

With the previous `v`, this will then print

```
0
2
4
6
Caught 8
```

You can't have a templated lambda, but you can use a lambda within a template:

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    std::for_each(
        v.begin(),v.end(),
        [](T const& t){std::cout<<t<<std::endl;}); // print each value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly template a lambda, but perhaps you can make a templated lambda factory:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct make_adder
{
  static inline std::function<T(T,T)> create()
  {
    return [](T a, T b){ return a + b; };
  }
};
```

Or even:

```
template <typename T> std::function<T(T,T)> make_adder
{
    return [](T a, T b){ return a + b; };
}
```

Then you can create a couple of instances:

```
auto int_adder = make_adder<int>::create();
auto black_adder = make_adder<Black>::create();
```

Not sure if you would need to create lambdas in that way, but if you find you do, then templating can be achieved by such a wrapper.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for making create() a static method withing a templated class rather than a templated global function?  Convention?

Comment: @mmocny: Err... no reason, I was just in "think struct" mode. Yes, a function would suffice! Let me edit.